# VB.net/asp.net: save Session as ArrayList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, arraylist, session-variables

I want to save some strings in a `Session("myKey")` as an ArrayList in my asp.net application.

So I have somthing like that:

```
Dim s As String = "String1"
```

If I use

```
Session("myKey") = s
```

it is working for the moment.

After PostBack I want to add another string to the session.

If do the same thing again, then i will overwrite my Sessiondata.

So I'm searching for something like this:

```
Dim s As String = "String1"
TryCast(Session("myKey"), ArrayList).Add(s)
```

In this case the Sessiondata would be stored correctly, but my code is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried and found a solution by myself;

```
Dim s As String = "String1"

  If Session("myKey") Is Nothing Then
        Session("myKey") = New ArrayList
  End If

TryCast(Session("myKey"), ArrayList).Add(s)
```

Don't know if it is the usual way, but it is working.

Comment: You should be using 'List(Of String)' rather than ArrayList. ArrayList isn't officially deprecated, but using a strongly typed list is much better practice.